# How to detect a failed form POST because of no network connection?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

I'm having an issue (with just one browser, Safari) that when a form is submitted (using `POST`), and if there's no network connection, the browser doesn't show the local 404 status page.

This might be due to using `iFrame` in Safari. If I do a manual refresh of the browser, the page is shown.

So I'm thinking that I can force a refresh using javascript if the POST changes its state to 'failed' (I can see the state changing from 'pending' (must be retrying) to 'failed' once it times out).

How can I detect this event in `javascript` so that I can force a refresh?

Comment: How are you posting the data?  Are you using jQuery or vanilla JavaScript (or some other library)?  You should be able to add error handling for the network state in any case.

Comment: I'm actually modifying an old asp page with its old way of posting a form. But I'm able to intercept the form post with jquery. I just don't know how to detect the failed post.